# Scraping issue using BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, tags

I am starting coding for myself and I am blocked on a code line. Can you provide me some explications ?

I want to scrape informations from this div tag :

`role = experience1_div('span', {'class' : 'mr1 t-bold'}) print(role)`

Output :

`[<span class="mr1 t-bold"> <span aria-hidden="true"><!-- -->Automation Engineer - Intern<!-- --></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!-- -->Automation Engineer - Intern<!-- --></span> </span>]`

How can I get only the HTML text : "Automation Engineer - Intern"

I tried this function `.get_text().strip()` but it seems that the `span` tag is blocking my function....

Comment: Well asked/focused question - Just a bit improvment e.g. more details / context would be great, so everybody could reproduce the selection of your `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue in provided information is that you have generated a `ResultSet` - To get its text you have to pick the element directly or iterate it.

```
role[0].span.get_text(strip=True)
```

or

```
for e in role:
    print(e.span.get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Automation Engineer - Intern
```

---

Better approach would be to select your element more specific (based on your example):

```
experience1_div.select_one('span.mr1.t-bold > span').get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it's working correctly and got my mistake ✓

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `experience1_div` is but to get all text use `role.text`

```
role = experience1_div.find('span', {'class' : 'mr1 t-bold'}) 
print(role.text)
```

output:
 `Automation Engineer - InternAutomation Engineer - Intern`

To get text from the first nested span, use
`role.span.text`

or from the second nested span
`role.contents[2].text`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest technique to achieve your aim.

> ```
> role = experience1_div.select_one('span.mr1.t-bold >span').get_text(strip=True)
>  
> print(role)
> ```